# Dragging line charts horizontally to show past/future data in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts is possible to drag and drop a series in a line chart, as explained [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dragDrop). But I need to drag the chart itself (i.e. the background) to show past/future data, not the lines. Is this possible with Highcharts? I couldn't find a way in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe just a panning option will fit your requirements? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xu36wmj4/ -> keep the `alt` button clicked and do a drag on the chart. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.panning

Comment: Yes, pressing `alt` and dragging the chart did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I answered your question with the suggestion from the comment - could be useful for others users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - using the panning feature is a looking solution for this case.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xu36wmj4/

```
chart: {
    panning: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'xy'
    },
    panKey: 'alt',
    zoomType: 'xy'
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.panning

Comment: Sebastian, how do I detect that the user dragged all the way to the left? I want to receive an event to load more data so the user can continue dragging.

Comment: @ps0604 I think that a good approach will be using the `afterSetExtremes` callback and compare the current `max` value to the `oldMax` value to detect if it was dragged to the left. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes